# I want to display clients based on a five day week on a form (All 5 days at once)

Tags: ms-access

I've got a list of clients who have certain tasks done on a weekly basis.  Currently we use an excel spreadsheet that keeps track of this but I am in the works of automating it.  In the process of moving this into our MS Access system, I have created a form that does this for a single day and can display a report that outputs in the manner I want the form to look but I cannot get the form to look like that so the user can see all the days of the week for all the clients at once.  I suppose I could do this in a subform per client but it seems a bit messy...

The spreadsheet we currently use has Column headers that state the Date and the rows are sort of grouped up by client that are for the number of times the given action occured, the timestamp of when it happened and other various data that happened on that day.

For the life of me I cannot think of a way to view all the records for that given week, grouped in detail per client all at once on the form.  I can think of some ways to do this through VBA with recordsets but would like to know is there is a simpler way to do this that is easier to maintain.

Is there a way to do this with the use of a query and a few small scale tricks that don't involve storing recordsets?  Keep in mind that this is for Access 2000, I only wish we would upgrade to '03.

Comment: Is there some reason you've ruled out subdatasheets?

Comment: Why not use five subforms?  One for today, another for tomorrow, etc for the next five business days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why not use five subforms? One for today, another for tomorrow, etc for
>   the next five business days. – Tony Toews Sep 12 at 20:57

That is the answer I've gone with and it works BEAUTIFULLY with the setup we are using.  Thanks for the wonderful idea!